# Is there a GUI software that exports chess diagrams for chess authors?

Tags: software, books, linux, windows

Is there a program either Linux or a Windows program that can create a chess position and save it as an image. That image can then be used by the chess author in a book that is being written.

Comment: You should generally first use the search function to see if your question has been previously asked. Had you done so you would have found this https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14686/high-quality-not-bitmap-diagram-software question. There are several good answers which you might find useful.

Comment: @BrianTowers They were seeming to be CLI apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chessbase products have to capability to export an image or using a chess diagram font as rtf to be pasted directly into word.

Comment: The Chess Assistant and Aquarium programs from chessok might also have similar capabilities, but I haven't looked at them recently.